# How to create a generic Repository class? (Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, repository, dao

in my Android app I use MVVM model with repositories
most of my DAO and Repositories classes are almost identical, so I figured I could reuse some code by creating generic equivalents that are later extended

this worked fine for my DAO classes:

```
@Dao
interface BaseDao<T> {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(vararg entity: T)
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertList(entities: List<T>)
    @Update
    suspend fun update(entity: T)
    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(entity: T)
}
```

```
@Dao
interface SettingDao : BaseDao<Setting> {
    @Query("SELECT value FROM settings WHERE id = :settingName")
    fun get(settingName: String): LiveData<String>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM settings ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<List<Setting>>
    @Query("DELETE FROM settings")
    suspend fun deleteAll()
}
```

now I want to do something similar for repository, but I cannot figure out how
this is what I've tried (I get error `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to: Setting[]`) in `BaseRepository$insert$2.invokeSuspend`

```
abstract class BaseRepository<T>(private val baseDao: BaseDao<T>) {
    suspend fun update(entity: T) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { baseDao.update(entity) }
    }
    suspend fun insert(entity: T) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { baseDao.insert(entity) }
    }
    suspend fun delete(entity: T) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { baseDao.delete(entity) }
    }
}
```

```
class SettingRepository(private val settingDao: SettingDao) : BaseRepository<Setting>(settingDao) {

    val company = settingDao.get("company")
    val ip = settingDao.get("ip")

    suspend fun deleteAll() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { settingDao.deleteAll() }
    }
}
```

My intuition is that I have to adjust this bit `private val baseDao: BaseDao<T>` in `BaseRepository`, but I cannot figure out how

And 2nd question - is there a way to get a generic table name in DAO, so I could put

```
    @Query("DELETE FROM settings")
    suspend fun deleteAll()
```

in the generic interface as well (in this case replace `settings` with entity's `tableName`